# SQL Carriage Return

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, carriage-return

I'm making an Oracle Apex editor but it's not working properly. I'm trying to add a *carriage return* to a value in a "Rich Text Editor"

E.g: `Hi i'm a select and i want to be your friend` have to become this: `Hi i'm a select [CR or CRLF] and i want to be your friend`

I also tried putting "ascii(13)" where I want to put a CR but I get this: "select49".

Char(13) and chr(13) aren't working either.

What can I do to put in a CR?

Oracle Version: 11g - Apex Version: 4.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd probably want to use CRLF instead of just CR:

```
SELECT 'Hi I am a select' ||
       CHR(13) || -- CR 
       CHR(10) || -- LF
       'and I want to be your friend'
FROM   dual
```

Comment: ok, thanks for the CFLR advice @a_horse_with_no_name, btw Mureinik, unfortunately it isn't working... when i click the button it seems like it don't recognise "chr(13)" at all, it don't do anything... the "select" word don't change...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Although CR/LF vs LF is debatable, I think Mureinik is right that CR/LF is always better than just CR.  I don't think any modern OS works well with only CR.  And sometimes its behavior can be extremely weird.  For example, run this on SQL*Plus on Windows or Solaris: `select 'Line 1'||chr(13)||'Line 2'||chr(10) from dual;`.  (The output kind of makes sense if you think of CR and LF in a typewriter.)

Comment: Ok, it works now, a tips that might help you all, this "trick" don't works with a rich text editor, but only with a simple TextArea, or better that's what happen to me, there might be another way to make it works with a Rich Text Editor, but i didn't found it yet. thanks again you all guys!